# Entity framework for sqlite in android development in android studio?

Tags: android, entity-framework, sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite

As we all know that microsoft gives facility of entity framework generation for sqlserver for the code first approach for sql connection and operations.

Is there any similar facility available for android app development in android studio.
so we don't need to do the code for database management for sqlite.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like this: http://www.sitepoint.com/5-best-android-orms/ ?

If yes - I would like to recommend Active Android lib.

Comment: any of this automatically generates the model class?